# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

After moving the project for another team project i start to get the following error when, running a unit test, an assert fails:

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UTFResources, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
>     System.IO.FileNotFoundException

There is no failed references for the test project

Comment: my answer is here. for such issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28087342/installed-microsoft-visualstudio-qualitytools-unittestframework-does-not-appear/75199838#75199838

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by removing :
`Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework`
'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.Extension'

and adding `Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework Version=10.1.0.0', the last version available on my instalation.

Extension dll was not even available to add.